# Boolean logic in VBA

Tags: vba, boolean-operations

I see unexpected behavior when using two AND operators and numbers: The third entry seems to be considered modulo 2. See the example below.

I would love to find out why the behavoir is like it is.

```
Sub Test()

Dim a As Boolean
Dim b As Boolean

a = True And 1 And 2 ' a = false
b = True And 2 And 3 ' b = true

MsgBox (a)
MsgBox (b)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`And` is applied bitwise here

```
    1111  'true
And 0001  '1
And 0010  '2
-------------
    0000  '0 -> evaluates to false when cast as boolean

    1111 'true
And 0010 '2
And 0011 '3
-------------
    0010 '2 -> evaluates to true when cast as boolean
```